# Adding Accessory Type moves Label in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to create something like a radio button; however, I am using a `UITableView`. I have the following code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "sortcell")
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Student"
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Teacher"
    }
    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .Center
    cell.textLabel?.font = getFont(17.5)
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

var selectedIndexPath = 10

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selected = true

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        sort = "Student"
        let cell = sortTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        cell?.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        let otherIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)
        let otherCell = sortTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(otherIndexPath)
        otherCell?.accessoryType = .None
    } else {
        sort = "Teacher"
        let cell = sortTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        cell?.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        let otherIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
        let otherCell = sortTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(otherIndexPath)
        otherCell?.accessoryType = .None
    }

    sortTable.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

}
```

This allows the user to switch between choosing whether he or she is a student or a teacher. However, when the `accessoryType` is added, the text label moves slightly, as shown:

Default:
[image: Default]

When tapped:
[image: When tapped]

How should I resolve this? I would like the text label to stay in the same place instead of shifting towards the left. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `textLabel.textAlignment` to `.Left`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the Check Mark pushes the view to left. You may need to customised your cell's view